# Quel est le sens de «cela tourne et se tient»?

Tags: expressions, traduction

Comment traduire l'expression «cela tourne et se tient» dans la citation suivante?

> Elle se souvient, après les coups de Samir, après la torture du
>   tatouage, de ces mois à repousser la mort, allongé sur sa natte à
>   terre, cette terre qui gardait la trace de tous les martyrs, et elle
>   sent comme cela *tourne* et *se tient*, toutes les douleurs humaines
>   dans le bruit des combats.

Dois-je interpréter *tourner* en tant que "devenir aigre", et *tenir* au sens de "résister" ou "se maintenir"?

La source du texte est le livre merveilleux de Véronique Olmi, intitulé Bakhita.

Comment: Je conseille de donner un contexte plus large et la source du passage: "Bakhita" de Véronique Olmi. D'après une recherche rapide, la personne dont il est question par "elle" est alors à l'hopital et lutte contre une grave maladie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lisant le passage entier (disponible [ici](https://books.google.be/books?id=VYYpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT242&lpg=PT242&dq=Elle+se+souvient,+apr%C3%A8s+les+coups+de+Samir,+apr%C3%A8s+la+torture+du+tatouage,+de+ces+mois+%C3%A0+repousser+la+mort,+allong%C3%A9+sur+sa+natte+%C3%A0+terre,+cette+terre+qui+gardait+la+trace+de+tous+les+martyrs,+et+elle+sent+comme+cela+tourne+et+se+tient,+toutes+les+douleurs+humains+dans+le+bruit+des+combats.&source=bl&ots=Z29paskysO&sig=ACfU3U1-wOKaEBRNb1LKmxinTzLVk2aUbQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM58zu9MPoAhVVeH0KHbdlDHkQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Elle%20se%20souvient%2C%20apr%C3%A8s%20les%20coups%20de%20Samir%2C%20apr%C3%A8s%20la%20torture%20du%20tatouage%2C%20de%20ces%20mois%20%C3%A0%20repousser%20la%20mort%2C%20allong%C3%A9%20sur%20sa%20natte%20%C3%A0%20terre%2C%20cette%20terre%20qui%20gardait%20la%20trace%20de%20tous%20les%20martyrs%2C%20et%20elle%20sent%20comme%20cela%20tourne%20et%20se%20tient%2C%20toutes%20les%20douleurs%20humains%20dans%20le%20bruit%20des%20combats.&f=false)), on peut constater que la syntaxe en est délibérément hachée et peu claire, avec des phrases juxtaposées s'enchaînant sans connecteurs logiques, un procédé littéraire proche du *stream of consciousness* sans doute pour rendre l'état de confusion dans lequel le personnage, malade et délirant, se trouve, entre ses sensations et ses souvenirs.

Le sujet de "se tient" n'est pas clair: il peut s'agir soit de "cela", soit de "elle". Le référent de "cela" n'est pas clair non plus.

On peut comprendre le passage de deux manières:

1)  "Cela tourne" est clair et est une expression courante: cela signifie que le personnage est victime de vertiges ou d'étourdissements, et qu'il a la sensation que tout tourne autour de lui.

*Cela se tient* signifie généralement "cela est cohérent", ce qui ne semble pas correspondre au contexte.

*Elle se tient* semble mieux coller alors au contexte (qui est celui d'une personne clouée au lit à l'hôpital avec une grave maladie et luttant contre la fièvre): on peut comprendre alors que lorsque "cela tourne" , elle *se tient* aux barreaux de son lit ou à autre chose auquel elle peut se raccrocher, ce qui est un geste naturel lorsqu'on est pris d'un vertige ou un étourdissement.

"Toutes les douleurs humaines dans le bruit des combats" peut être alors une ellipse pour "toutes les douleurs humaines se trouvant dans le bruit des combats".

OU: "toutes les douleurs humaines dans le bruit de combats" est un complément de "gardait". Une syntaxe plus claire aurait alors été :

> cette terre qui gardait la trace de tous les martyrs, toutes les douleurs humaines dans le bruit des combats. Et elle sent comme cela tourne et se tient.

2) "Cela" se réfère à "toutes les douleurs humaines dans le bruit des combats", et le sens est alors plus métaphorique.

Dans ce cas, ce sont les douleurs humaines qui tournent (le personnage a alors la sensation d'être au milieu du tournis de ces douleurs humaines dans les combats). Ces "douleurs humaines dans le bruit des combats" *se tiennent*, c'est-à-dire qu'elles forment un tout cohérent.

On pourrait alors reformuler comme suit:

> elle sent comme toutes les douleurs humaines tournent et se tiennent, dans le bruit des combats

Comment: Greg, merci pour ta réponse claire et exhaustive! ;)